# Employee Time Clock Calculation

Tags: c#, datetime, time, timespan

I am hoping someone can help me with a optimal solution for this. I have a list of time logs. It contains a datatime entry for each clockin per employee per day.

I am trying to come up with a good solution to calculate the time worked per day. The time lapsed between each clock-in and clock-out for one employee.

The final result must give me the following.

- Total Time Worked
- Total Time Out
- The time lapsed between each log / row to extract and show times worked and  times out.

For example 
ClockIn : 06:00
ClockedOut : 10:00
ClockedIn : 10:15

BreakTime = 00:15

and so on.

I am trying to avoid using to many for loops / foreach loops.

This is a sample piece of code representing what the list of time logs is. The type is. I = for Clock-In and O = Clock-Out. Each Shift has a Block Start Time and Block End Time.

```
var blockStart = new TimeSpan(0,6,0,0,0);
var blockEnd = new TimeSpan(0,17,0,0);

var listOfTimeLogs = new List<TimeLog>()
        {
            new TimeLog() {EntryDateTime = new DateTime(2016,05,20,6,0,0),Type = "I"},
            new TimeLog() {EntryDateTime = new DateTime(2016,05,20,10,0,0),Type = "O"},
            new TimeLog() {EntryDateTime = new DateTime(2016,05,20,10,15,0),Type = "I"},
            new TimeLog() {EntryDateTime = new DateTime(2016,05,20,12,0,0),Type = "O"},
            new TimeLog() {EntryDateTime = new DateTime(2016,05,20,12,30,0),Type = "I"},
            new TimeLog() {EntryDateTime = new DateTime(2016,05,20,15,0,0),Type = "O"},
            new TimeLog() {EntryDateTime = new DateTime(2016,05,20,15,15,0),Type = "I"},
            new TimeLog() {EntryDateTime = new DateTime(2016,05,20,18,00,0),Type = "O"}
        };
```

Hope this make sense. any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Whers did you get stuck? If there is always i,o,i,o...pattern you can do this with one pass. Give as a result that you are expecting from that input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computers are made to do loops.

Here is a [sample](https://ideone.com/0pHFSy) of how I would handle the problem.

**Program.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TimeClock
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var blockStart = new TimeSpan(0, 6, 0, 0);
            var blockEnd = new TimeSpan(0, 17, 0, 0);

            var listOfTimeLogs = new List<TimeLog>
            {
                new TimeLog {EntryDateTime = new DateTime(2016,05,20,6,0,0),EntryType = EntryTypes.In},
                new TimeLog {EntryDateTime = new DateTime(2016,05,20,10,0,0),EntryType = EntryTypes.Out},
                new TimeLog {EntryDateTime = new DateTime(2016,05,20,10,15,0),EntryType = EntryTypes.In},
                new TimeLog {EntryDateTime = new DateTime(2016,05,20,12,0,0),EntryType = EntryTypes.Out},
                new TimeLog {EntryDateTime = new DateTime(2016,05,20,12,30,0),EntryType = EntryTypes.In},
                new TimeLog {EntryDateTime = new DateTime(2016,05,20,15,0,0),EntryType = EntryTypes.Out},
                new TimeLog {EntryDateTime = new DateTime(2016,05,20,15,15,0),EntryType = EntryTypes.In},
                new TimeLog {EntryDateTime = new DateTime(2016,05,20,18,00,0),EntryType = EntryTypes.Out}
            };


            // You are going to have have for / for each unless you use Linq

            // fist I would count clock in's versus the out's
            var totalIn = listOfTimeLogs.Count(e => e.EntryType == EntryTypes.In);
            var totalOut = listOfTimeLogs.Count() - totalIn;

            // check if we have in the number of time entries
            if (totalIn > totalOut)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Employee didn't clock out");
            }

            // as I was coding this sample program, i thought of another way to store the time
            // I would store them in blocks - we have to loop
            var timeBlocks = new List<TimeBlock>();
            for (var x = 0; x < listOfTimeLogs.Count; x += 2)
            {
                // create a new WORKING block based on the in/out time entries
                timeBlocks.Add(new TimeBlock
                {
                    BlockType = BlockTypes.Working,
                    In = listOfTimeLogs[x],
                    Out = listOfTimeLogs[x + 1]
                });

                // create a BREAK block based on gaps
                // check if the next entry in a clock in
                var breakOut = x + 2;
                if (breakOut < listOfTimeLogs.Count)
                {
                    var breakIn = x + 1;
                    // create a new BREAK block
                    timeBlocks.Add(new TimeBlock
                    {
                        BlockType = BlockTypes.Break,
                        In = listOfTimeLogs[breakIn],
                        Out = listOfTimeLogs[breakOut]
                    });
                }
            }

            var breakCount = 0;
            // here is a loop for displaying detail
            foreach (var block in timeBlocks)
            {
                var lineTitle = block.BlockType.ToString();
                // this is me trying to be fancy
                if (block.BlockType == BlockTypes.Break)
                {
                    if (block.IsBreak())
                    {
                        lineTitle = $"Break #{++breakCount}";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lineTitle = "Lunch";
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine($" {lineTitle,-10} {block}  ===  Length: {block.Duration.ToString(@"hh\:mm")}");
            }

            // calculating total time for each block type
            var workingTime = timeBlocks.Where(b => b.BlockType == BlockTypes.Working)
                    .Aggregate(new TimeSpan(0), (p, v) => p.Add(v.Duration));

            var breakTime = timeBlocks.Where(b => b.BlockType == BlockTypes.Break)
                    .Aggregate(new TimeSpan(0), (p, v) => p.Add(v.Duration));


            Console.WriteLine($"\nTotal Working Hours: {workingTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm")}");
            Console.WriteLine($"   Total Break Time: {breakTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm")}");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**TimeBlock.cs**

```cs
using System;

namespace TimeClock
{
    public enum BlockTypes
    {
        Working,
        Break
    }

    public class TimeBlock
    {
        public BlockTypes BlockType;
        public TimeLog In;
        public TimeLog Out;

        public TimeSpan Duration
        {
            get
            {
                // TODO: Need error checking
                return Out.EntryDateTime.Subtract(In.EntryDateTime);
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"In: {In.EntryDateTime:HH:mm} - Out: {Out.EntryDateTime:HH:mm}";
        }

    }

    // a little extension class
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static bool IsBreak(this TimeBlock block)
        {
            // if the length of the break period is less than 19 minutes
            // we will consider it a break, the person could have clock IN late
            return block.Duration.TotalMinutes < 19 ? true : false;

        }

    }

}
```

**TimeLog.cs**

```cs
using System;

namespace TimeClock
{
    public class TimeLog
    {
        public DateTime EntryDateTime;
        public EntryTypes EntryType;
    }
}
```

**EntryTypes.cs**

```cs
namespace TimeClock
{
    public enum EntryTypes
    {
        In,
        Out
    }
}
```

[image: Output of Program]

Comment: Black Frog - Thank you so much for the input. much appreciated. Exactly what i needed.

Comment: I like the Little extension you added. Can certainly use that as part of the rules i need to implement for the shifts.

Comment: No problem and glad you like it.